# python match variable to dict key and return value

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I'm a python noob, trying to take a variable, match this to a dictionary key and then return the value of the matching key.  If it doesn't match any, continue loop.  The goal is to create a crude user database so that user input can choose the corresponding class instance of the same name.

I'm getting a syntax error:
if name == account_list[]:
SyntaxError: invalid syntax (pointing to the 2nd []).  Is there a syntax to make this work, or am I off base here?  Thanks in advance for the help.

```
class BankAccount():
     balance = 0.0
     account_owner = ""
     def welcome(self):
          print("Welcome, " + self.account_owner.name + "!")

account_list = {
"Matty": mattyAccount
"Hannah": hannahAccount
..etc
}
name = input("Enter Username:\n")
while name != account_list[]:
     print("Not recognized.")
else:
     account_list[name].welcome()
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: What do you expect `account_list[]` to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `in` keyword in python.

```
if name in account_list:
    account_list[name].welcome()
else
    print("Not recognized")
```

If you want to loop until the user is entering a valid name:

```
while(True):
    name = input("Enter Username:\n")
    if name in account_list:
        account_list[name].welcome()
        break # Will exit the while loop.
    else
        print("Not recognized... Try again...")
```

Comment: That's a huge help, "@adrien Logut" but how can I make that loop until it does match?